# How to mark the question as duplicate with reputation of 2000+ points

Tags: support

I do not have option to mark the question as duplicate. Please suggest me how to do it.

Duplicate question :

[Apache hadoop combiners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474456/apache-hadoop-combiners)

Old question of same type:

[Combiner Inplementation and internal working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406566/combiner-inplementation-and-internal-working/)

Comment: Just do what you did, (add a comment) and someone else will vote to close it.

Comment: You can flag it. Click "Flag" > "duplicate of..." > Paste the link in the bar. This pops the question in the close queue for other (higher rep) users to see and vote on.

Comment: You can propose duplicates using a flag? Close voting privileges are available from 3k rep on.

Comment: This is [explained in the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) - so a duplicate of any question where that is actually the answer.

Comment: The Help Center encourages commenting, and only flagging 'if the question has serious problems (e.g. it is spam or offensive)'

Comment: @ergonaut Not exactly. Adding a comment doesn't throw a post into a review queue, it just tells people who happen to pass by, and not many people read comments to begin with, never mind click on the link. I've seen that happen so many times: and questions *rarely* get closed that way.

Comment: Seems like the `flag>should be closed>duplicate of` option has been removed. I can only see after `flag` the options `spam`, `rude or abusive` and `in need of moderator intervention`. Or does it only appear for people with higher reputation?

Comment: Higher reputation AFAIk.

Answer (score 23):

Closing as a duplicate requires the [Close Vote Privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Duplicate votes are essentially close/reopen votes.

This privilege is awarded at 3k rep here on Stack Overflow. As you only have 2.1k at the time of this writing, you don't have enough rep for the privilege. Just 900 away!

---

If you would like to see a question closed as a duplicate, you can use Flags. By clicking the Flag button on the bottom of a question, you can go to:

> Flag > Should Be Closed... > Duplicate Of... > The question that this should point to

This will send that post into a review queue, where members of the community with adequate close vote privileges will be able to decide whether the question should be closed, or left open.